# Why does my LibreOffice look like a 90s Linux GUI?

Tags: libreoffice

Few days ago I installed Elementary OS on a used laptop, then LibreOffice. I somehow found out how to activate ribbons, but next to the 90s black & white bevels on the menu tabs, most icons have a white background colour:

[image: Screenshot of LibreOffice]

Later on I watched a Youtube video about office software for Elementary OS and that guy's version looks way better than mine (starting at 0:17):

https://youtu.be/v-DpSSXWL0c?t=17

What's wrong on my side, is there anything I need to adjust in the settings of LibreOffice?

Comment: I too wondered about this but no explanation from the creator was given.
RJ | [The Greats Walls](https://thegreatretainingwallsofsantamonica.com/)

Answer (score 4):

You can improve LibreOffice's looks and integration into elementary OS by adding the `libreoffice-gtk3` package.

You might also like the `libreoffice-style-elementary` package that includes better fitting tool icons too.

To install both, open Terminal and enter the following command.

```
sudo apt install libreoffice-gtk3 libreoffice-style-elementary
```

Comment: I installed that style package and while the icons look slightly better (no antique floppy disk icon anymore), I now have two ribbon menus, one with completely white background...

Answer (score 1):

I asked myself the same thing. For a distro like Elementary Os - which makes the look & feel a priority point, the integration of Libre Writer is simply ugly.

I use Ghost Writer + Pandoc + Wkhtmltox. None of them in the repo...